# How can I fix an "exit code 11" when compiling with Clang?

Tags: ios, llvm

I am using Xcode version 4.6.3.

For the last two days, everything has been working fine, but today I'm hitting this problem:

```
ProcessPCH /Users/hits1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/oneText-ehzdbhdloyrhhlciicbdjtvrzzeq/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/oneText-Prefix-apnbnwripekzjoazxfvojavjevfd/oneText-Prefix.pch.pth oneText/oneText-Prefix.pch normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd /Users/hits1/Desktop/DataIOS/oneText
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c-header -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wno-receiver-is-weak -Wduplicate-method-match -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -mios-simulator-version-min=6.1 -iquote /Users/hits1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/oneText-ehzdbhdloyrhhlciicbdjtvrzzeq/Build/Intermediates/oneText.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/oneText.build/oneText-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/hits1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/oneText-ehzdbhdloyrhhlciicbdjtvrzzeq/Build/Intermediates/oneText.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/oneText.build/oneText-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/hits1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/oneText-ehzdbhdloyrhhlciicbdjtvrzzeq/Build/Intermediates/oneText.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/oneText.build/oneText-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/hits1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/oneText-ehzdbhdloyrhhlciicbdjtvrzzeq/Build/Intermediates/oneText.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/oneText.build/oneText-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/hits1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/oneText-ehzdbhdloyrhhlciicbdjtvrzzeq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include -I/Users/hits1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/oneText-ehzdbhdloyrhhlciicbdjtvrzzeq/Build/Intermediates/oneText.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/oneText.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/hits1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/oneText-ehzdbhdloyrhhlciicbdjtvrzzeq/Build/Intermediates/oneText.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/oneText.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/hits1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/oneText-ehzdbhdloyrhhlciicbdjtvrzzeq/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator --serialize-diagnostics /Users/hits1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/oneText-ehzdbhdloyrhhlciicbdjtvrzzeq/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/oneText-Prefix-apnbnwripekzjoazxfvojavjevfd/oneText-Prefix.pch.dia -c /Users/hits1/Desktop/DataIOS/oneText/oneText/oneText-Prefix.pch -o /Users/hits1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/oneText-ehzdbhdloyrhhlciicbdjtvrzzeq/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/oneText-Prefix-apnbnwripekzjoazxfvojavjevfd/oneText-Prefix.pch.pth -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/hits1/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/oneText-ehzdbhdloyrhhlciicbdjtvrzzeq/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/oneText-Prefix-apnbnwripekzjoazxfvojavjevfd/oneText-Prefix.pch.d





Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 11
```

I don't know about this problem. I've never seen this sort of problem before.

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: u were changed the project name also change the another location

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik it's jest empty project my problem is ever project it's showing like this.My old projects also showing like this Please give me any idea

Comment: this error means u were changed the project name and change the path also , thats y the .pch (compiler)does not identify the correct name /path . got it

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://myioslearning.blogspot.com/2014/12/how-to-remove-apple-llvm-60-error-ios.html) will be helpful. It works for me every time. Apple LLVM error occurs when you are running you program after every minute. Means you are running the program for testing a lot. Hope that link helps you.